# How do I get the access type in WordPress?

Tags: user-access, mobile, responsive

How do I get the access type (from desktop or mobile) in WordPress?

Here is a possible solution posted [here](http://qianduanblog.com/post/php-get-access-source.html).

```
function yundanran_get_access_type()
{
    $is_wap=false;

    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $mobile_agents = Array
    (
        "240x320","acer","acoon","acs-","abacho","ahong","airness",
        "alcatel","amoi","android","anywhereyougo.com","applewebkit/525",
        "applewebkit/532","asus","audio","au-mic","avantogo",
        "becker","benq","bilbo","bird","blackberry","blazer","bleu",
        "cdm-","compal","coolpad","danger","dbtel","dopod","elaine",
        "eric","etouch","fly ","fly_","fly-","go.web","goodaccess",
        "gradiente","grundig","haier","hedy","hitachi","htc",
        "huawei","hutchison","inno","ipad","ipaq","ipod","jbrowser",
        "kddi","kgt","kwc","lenovo","lg ","lg2","lg3","lg4","lg5",
        "lg7","lg8","lg9","lg-","lge-","lge9","longcos","maemo",
        "mercator","meridian","micromax","midp","mini","mitsu",
        "mmm","mmp","mobi","mot-","moto","nec-","netfront","newgen",
        "nexian","nf-browser","nintendo","nitro","nokia","nook",
        "novarra","obigo","palm","panasonic","pantech","philips",
        "phone","pg-","playstation","pocket","pt-","qc-","qtek",
        "rover","sagem","sama","samu","sanyo","samsung","sch-",
        "scooter","sec-","sendo","sgh-","sharp","siemens","sie-",
        "softbank","sony","spice","sprint","spv","symbian","tablet",
        "talkabout","tcl-","teleca","telit","tianyu","tim-","toshiba",
        "tsm","up.browser","utec","utstar","verykool","virgin","vk-",
        "voda","voxtel","vx","wap","wellco","wig browser","wii",
        "windows ce","wireless","xda","xde","zte"
    );
    $is_wap = false;
    foreach ($mobile_agents as $device) 
    {
        if (stristr($user_agent, $device)) 
        {
            $is_wap = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $is_wap?'wap':'web';
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress question...but instead of re-inventing the wheel take a look at [this](http://mobiledetect.net/).  I use it in any of my sites where I need to detect mobile device, and it works great.  I see on their page they even mention there are WP plugins that use this code.